# Delete trailing marks ]]

Tags: python, regex

Doing some regex and I can't sus out how I can get rid of the ]] marks from this string

Regex:

```
<title><!\[CDATA\[(.*?)</title>
```

String:

```
<item>
            <title><![CDATA[Coronation Street star Jean Alexander dies aged 90]]></title>
            <description>
```

Returned:
Coronation Street star Jean Alexander dies aged 90]]

What I want returned:
Coronation Street star Jean Alexander dies aged 90

Comment: `<title><!\[CDATA\[(.*?\]\])</title>`

Comment: As easy as getting the inner text from that title node using xpath or dom. Or, if there is pressure on regex, use `<title><!\[CDATA\[(.*?)]]</title>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I infer that you'd like an answer with respect to using a regex with python.  So, here's some code that performs the desired action:

```
import re
string = "<title><![CDATA[Coronation Street star Jean Alexander dies aged 90]]></title>"
result = re.findall(r"\[.*\[(.*?)\]\]", string)
print ' '.join(result)
```

Note: this code runs under python 2.8
May run code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQzAxQ2pfRWxBekU).

A few points about the code.  The findall method of the regular expression object is available once the code imports that object. Your regex needs a little bit of tweaking in order for the two terminating brackets to not appear by *including them in the regex*.  Now, the result will be a list with the correct data and that list is then converted by next line of code into a string.

I find it easier personally using PHP for something like this, so I'll also show you a PHP solution that runs on PHP versions 5 and 7:

```
<?php
$subject = "[CDATA[Coronation Street star Jean Alexander dies aged 90]]";
$pattern = "/\[.*\[(.*?)\]\]/";
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

With PHP the result is immediately available as a string in element 1 of $matches as long as preg_match is successful.

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/9NVLl).

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the square brackets in the end too.

```
string = "<title><![CDATA[Coronation Street star Jean Alexander dies aged 90]]></title>"
result = re.findall(r"\[.*\[(.*?)\]\]", string)
print(result)
```